# With wp_insert_post inserting multiple posts, how can I make the first post the parent of the second?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wp_insert_post to create a "Franchise Launcher" which will deploy a default set of starter pages for a new franchise section of a Wordpress site. Things are working well so far, except that I need to generate six pages, with the first page being the parent of the following five. I'm testing that now with two pages using this code:

```
// Create Franchise Home
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Franchise',
  'post_content'  => 'This is the Home Page for the New Franchise',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_status'   => 'draft',
  'post_author'   => 4
);

// Insert the post into the database
$franchise_parent_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
echo "$franchise_parent_id";

// Create Franchise About Page
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Franchise About',
  'post_content'  => 'This is the About Page for the New Franchise',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_parent'   => $franchise_parent_id,
  'post_status'   => 'draft',
  'post_author'   => 4
);

// Insert the post into the database
$franchise_about_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
echo "$franchise_about_id";
```

This is working mostly. The two pages are created, and their IDs are echoed. What isn't working is the bit where the post parent of the second page is set by the id of the first page. Is there something I don't know about using a variable to set the post_parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to select the Draft page as Parent page, you might add the following filter into your plugin or theme.

```
add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'custom_args', 1, 1);

function custom_args($dropdown_args) {

    $dropdown_args['post_status'] = array('publish','draft');

    return $dropdown_args;
}
```

Comment: Oh cool thanks! Does that enable Drafts as Page Parents generally?

Comment: Yes it should, you have to check/test though.

Comment: Thanks so much for your tip! That worked perfectly, and it made the system I built so much more functional, to allow for the pages to be created as drafts rather than immediately published. Thanks @Mohsin !

Comment: @WilliamAlexander Happy to know that it worked! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, apparently with Rubber Duck Debugging. A Draft can't be a Parent. I changed the status to published and all worked perfectly.